# C++ style of constructor calling

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, language-lawyer

I have an object called `Thing`, its constructor takes an int.

This code works as expected:

`Thing thing(5);`

However, by accident I wrote the following:

`Thing thing = Thing(5);  // note: no 'new'`

And got the error `no matching constructor for initialization of 'Thing'`. What is the actual meaning of the latter code? I know what it means if I throw a `new` in there, but without new, what does that mean?

Comment: How does that happen? I didn't use `explicit` myself anywhere

Comment: @WhiZTiM `explicit` would prevent to call `Thing thing = 5` instead.

Comment: Show the whole class definition of `Thing`, or at least all its constructors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Thing thing(5);` is [direct initliazation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization), `thing` is constructed by the apporiate constructor (i.e. `Thing::Thing(int)`) directly.

`Thing thing = Thing(5);` is [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), which is not exact the same thing as direct initialization. But for this case, since C++17, it will invoke `Thing::Thing(int)` directly to construct the object too, then it has the same effect with direct initialization here.

> First, if `T` is a class type and the initializer is a prvalue expression whose cv-unqualified type is the same class as `T`, the initializer expression itself, rather that a temporary materialized from it, is used to initialize the destination object: see [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)

Before C++17, the 2nd case (i.e. copy initialization) requires copy/move constructor to be accessible and non-explicit; if that's the case and you're using a compiler not supporting C++17, that would cause the error.

> If `T` is a class type and the cv-unqualified version of the type of `other` is `T` or a class derived from `T`, the non-explicit constructors of `T` are examined and the best match is selected by overload resolution. The constructor is then called to initialize the object.

Note that from C++17, the code will compile fine. According to the rule of [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), the copy/move constructors are not required to be accessible and `explicit` for this case.

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are required to omit
>   the copy- and move- constructors of class objects even if copy/move
>   constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects:
>
> - In initialization, if the initializer expression is a prvalue and the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as the
>     class of the destination, the initializer expression is used to
>     initialize the destination object:
>
>   ```
>   T x = T(T(T())); // only one call to default constructor of T, to initialize x
>   ```

Comment: IMO you talk about `Thing thing = 5`, not `Thing thing = Thing(5)`. In the latter, making the constructor `Thing(int)` `explicit` is ok, as soon as a copy-constructor is defined (but this copy-constructor must not be `explicit`).

Answer (score 10):

```
Thing thing = Thing(5);
```

requires a (non-`explicit`) copy (or move)-constructor to be defined:

```
Thing(const Thing &);
```

(even if it's not called for optimization reasons).

Comment: I see, so that formulation is making a `Thing` then copying it (rather pointlessly).

Comment: You cannot conclude this without seeing class constructors/members

Comment: @P0W, since `Thing thing(5);` works, there is at least a constructor `Thing(int)` (`explicit` or not). If `Thing thing = Thing(5)` does not work, IMO we can conclude that a copy(/move)-constructor is missing. Could you provide a counter-example?

Comment: @Виталик Бушаев Yes.

Comment: @rom1v  Comments on this https://godbolt.org/g/o9AD0l ? Now I'm suprb curious to see OP's class definitions, compiler used and its flags. Or I am drunk

Comment: @P0W **If** `Thing thing(5)` works and `Thing thing = Thing(5)` does not work, **then** a non-explicit copy- (or move-) constructor is missing. You provide a sample that make both declaration work without defining explicitly a copy- (or move-) constructor. This is not incompatible ;-) A counter-example would be a working `Thing thing(5)`, a non-working `Thing thing = Thing(5)`, with a solution which make it work without defining a copy- (or move-) constructor.

Comment: `Thing(const Thing &)` is defined by default, as is the assignment operator; they may not be suitable for the class, but a default implementation exists.  This is why boost::noncopyable & the standard were changed, so that they could be removed

Comment: @rom1v I don't denying your statement in the previous comment. But I am curious what scenario OP has as to why it didn't work on first place. We can only make assumptions in this context.

Comment: @P0W For example, it may inherit a non-copyable class, or declare a field of a non-copyable type, so that the copy-constructor is implicitly deleted.

Comment: @P0W but you're right, I am also interested in the cause :)